# How do I get data from my Microsoft SQL Server database to populate fields in my Ranorex project?

Tags: ranorex

I’m failing to successfully bind module variables to data column.

I set up my Microsoft SQL Server and successfully connected to it remotely in my Ranorex project. [My database connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3M11.png)

I have two fields on my website I'm trying to populate using data from my SQL Server database: Age and Income.

I created variables for these two in my recording module.[The two variables: $age and $income](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQ44X.png)

I tried to bind the variables to my data source using information from Ranorex documentation. I think this is where I might be getting it wrong but I think I've done it correctly.
[Data Binding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2Aus.png)

So I'm expecting the data to be pulled from the database, but when I run the recording, it just uses the default value (value used as failsafe when it fails to get the value from the database). And it gives the following warning in the report: [Warning shown on report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8JAS.jpg)

What am I missing?